# Using a Fargate image as lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecr

I am using AWS Fargate to run a python based Docker image (stored in AWS ECR), and it is working as expected. The invocation is done by a lambda function, which populates the environment and then invokes the Fargate task.

Now I would like to use the same Docker image, but invoke it via SQS trigger. I defined a new function as follows:

```
def handler(event, context):
    print("Handler called!")
    print(orjson.dumps(event))
    print(orjson.dumps(context))
```

and attempted to invoke it by sending a test SQS message.

The docker image is using the following:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "/app/main.py", "run" ]
```

I would like to invoke the above handler function instead, and ensure that event and context are available to the handler. How can I embed the event and context as part of either ENTRYPOINT or CMD for the lambda handler?

Clarification:
Right now main.py is using click to handle command-line arguments. If I add another click command for invocation through lambda, the context and event parameters will be lost. I am trying to somehow call /app/main.py and invoke the "handler" function within it, passing event and context as the parameters to the handler function.

Comment: That looks fine. What issue are you seeing?

Comment: Updated question - I have no idea how to invoke main.py's handler function and pass the parameters to it

Comment: `ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "/app/main.py", "handler" ]`, would call your function, but what kind of types have your arguments (`event` and `context`) from `handler(event, context)` ? Those are the ones you need to pass in the `ENTRYPOINT`, correct ? It looks to me like you want to simulate an external specific event, like the SQS one ... If I understand right, you're looking to following something similar to the [AWS tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-example.html)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a native (elegant) way to pass event and context when you run a Fargate task. One option I have seen used is to save the content of event and context in two variables and then launch the ECS task passing those to variables via the `runTask` API (which I assume it's what you use when you say the Lambda "invokes the Fargate task"). You can do so by adding the `overrides` as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html).

One caveat here is that you'd need to modify the code to read event and context from these variables instead of being passed as part of calling the handler.